# Will a MATLAB function always echo its output argument?

Tags: matlab

I'm working on defining a simple MATLAB function that converts from rectangular to polar coordinates.

The function's input argument is an array of a rectangular coordinate, (x, y). Its output is another ordered pair: (r, θ), of polar coordinates, with θ in degrees.

The function works as expected for all valid input arrays.

The trouble is, MATLAB seems to be "ignoring" a semicolon and echoes the function's output argument, together with my desired output; a string printed with the fprintf function. I don't understand why.

Here's the code:

```
%This function converts from rectangular to polar coordinates.
function polar_pair = rect2polar(rectangular_pair)
r = sqrt((rectangular_pair(1)^2 + (rectangular_pair(2)^2)));
theta = rad2deg(atan(rectangular_pair(2) / rectangular_pair(1)));
polar_pair = [r theta];
fprintf('r = %2.2f\n, Angle = %3.2f\n', polar_pair);
end
```

I tried removing the formatted string, leaving only the function's output argument suppressed by the semicolon, and it still prints out the output argument:

```
%This function converts from rectangular to polar coordinates.
function polar_pair = rect2polar(rectangular_pair)
r = sqrt((rectangular_pair(1)^2 + (rectangular_pair(2)^2)));
theta = rad2deg(atan(rectangular_pair(2) / rectangular_pair(1)));
polar_pair = [r theta]; 
end
```

I understand that this implies the function will always display a result.

I then tried rewriting the code so input was given as separate integers, not an ordered pair in an array.

```
%This function converts from rectangular to polar coordinates.
function [radius, angle_theta] = rect2polar(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
  radius = sqrt((x_coordinate).^2 + (y_coordinate).^2);
  angle_theta = rad2deg(atan(y_coordinate ./ x_coordinate));
end
```

This worked. But I keep wondering if there is a way of preventing the echoing of the output argument in the first code block so that I have better control over how the output is displayed.

Comment: How do you call the function? `fprintf()` (same with `disp()`) will *force* feedback to the command window, i.e. display your variable. So of course using that will indeed print the variable. Otherwise, it's probably the function call you make. If you called `A = rect2polar(b)` (note: no semi-colon), either in a script, function or the command window,  it prints to the command window, as usual. If you call `A = rect2polar(b);` (note: semi-colon) it won't print, as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have some function

```
function out = myFunc( in )
   out = 10*in;
end
```

Then the semi-colon used on the line `out=10*in;` will suppress the output from being displayed in the command window at the time the line is executed. However, if you call it from somewhere else in your code like

```
myFunc( 5 )
```

Without a semi-colon, then the output of the function itself will be displayed in the command window.

You can suppress this in two ways. The first is to add a semi-colon when calling the function too (I suspect this is what you're missing)

```
myFunc( 5 );
```

The 2nd is to use `nargout` within the function

```
function out = myFunc( in )
   b = 10*in;
   if nargout > 0
      out = b;
   end
end
```

This causes the output to be undefined, and therefore not displayable, if the function is called without any outputs regardless of semi-colon e.g. `myFunc( 5 )`.

However, if you assign an output `a = myFunc( 5 )` without a semi-colon then `a` will be displayed.

Of course if you include an `fprintf` statement then you're directly asking for a command window output, I don't think that's a surprising result...

Comment: You're right! Using a semi-colon when calling the function too is the point I was missing. That solved the problem. Thanks! 
Though, I can't say I understand why fully.

Comment: You're calling a function which has at least one output, the default behaviour for lines without semi-colons is to display the output of that line